# non-normal covering of wedge of three circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

How might I systematically approach the task of finding a three-fold, non-normal covering of a wedge of three circles?  My instinct is to find a non-normal subgroup of the free group on 3 generators and try to sketch a space whose loops realize that subgroup.  As this is in preparation for an exam in algebraic topology, I think this is not the best way of approaching the problem and think there is perhaps some topological insight I am not exploiting.  Tips for how to approach such problems in general would also be greatly appreciated.  Prior coursework in abstract algebra is not presupposed for the course, so although I am not ignorant of abstract algebra, I am not as fluent as I once was with its more advanced techniques.

Comment: A non-normal cover is not going to be symmetric. A normal cover will have covering transformations that take any vertex to any other vertex.

Comment: I understand this aspect of the theory, but in practice have trouble visualizing such an object, so an example that realizes these requirements is what I think I need.

Comment: I like to color the three circles different colors. Then you need to construct an oriented graph where each vertex has one incoming and one outgoing end of an edge of each color. Since every 2-fold cover is normal, try a 3-fold cover. Draw three vertices and start connecting them up in various ways satisfying the requirements I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you can do it with a bouquet of two circles, you can
do it with a bouquet of three. Just hang an extra circle at the preimages
of the base-point.

Let $B$ be a bouquet of two circles, and $x$ the point where
they meet. The fundamental group $\pi_1$ is free on two generators, $g$ and $h$
corresponding to the two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ say. Then $\pi_1$ has a transitive
action on the three-point set $\{1,2,3\}$ via $g\mapsto(1,2)$
and $h\mapsto(2,3)$. Let us construct a covering space of $B$
embodying this action. Take three copies of $B$; call them $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$. Do some cut-and-paste on these. In $B_1$ and $B_2$ snip the circles $C_1$ and join each to the other one. In $B_2$ and $B_3$ snip the circles $C_2$ and join each to the other one. You get a covering space $B'$
of $B$ which is connected, triple, and one can check, non-abelian.

For a concrete model, take the four Euclidean circles, radii all one,
and centres $(1,0)$, $(3,0)$, $(5,0)$ and $(7,0)$. This covers $B$
with $\{(2,0),(4,0),(6,0)\}$ forming the fibre of $x$.

For the three-circle bouquet, you could add circles radius $1/2$
with centres at $(5/2,0)$, $(9/2,0)$ and $(13/2,0)$.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I really needed a good example like this to help me with the technique of such problems.